# Make second AJAX call to database while first is working

Tags: php, ajax, apache, cakephp, asynchronous

I have two AJAX calls, the first starts a long running script and the second polls a database table for a percentage field.  For some reason, when making the second AJAX call, the database call will always return false until after the first is done which defeats the purpose of polling a table for a percentage update.

First

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.DS.'controller'.DS.'long_running_script';?>",
        data: {
            file: "<?php echo $file;?>",
            id: "<?php echo $id;?>"
        },
        type: 'post',
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#loading").show();
            $('#progressbar').progressbar({
                value: false
            });
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $('#response').empty().html(data);
        },
        complete:function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Second

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var getProgress = $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.DS.'controller'.DS.'pending';?>",
        data: {
            id: "<?php echo $id;?>",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        complete: getProgress,
        timeout: 30000
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        getProgress.done(function(data){
            console.log(data.pending);
        });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

The second call that returns false requests a percentage field from the db that gets updated by the long running script.  I also noticed on my local machine, every HTTP request to the virtual host hangs until the first AJAX call is finished.  Is it possible the first call is somehow blocking connection to the server?

Comment: I've noticed that the first call blocks requests from the same browser on my machine.  I've had success with a second browser open which is able to send requests that aren't blocked by the first one.

Comment: Make second call from success of first call

Answer (score 0):

The problem was PHP putting a lock on the session file because of resource consumption between multiple AJAX calls.  [session_write_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) works however removes write permissions on the session file until starting the session again.  Using a custom session handler while saving sessions to a database instead of file seems to work pretty well as a long term solution.